# How to use different R versions to test packages with Travis-CI?

Tags: r, travis-ci

I use Travis to test R packages hosted on GitHub (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/humburg/tileHMM)). That works great except that I don't seem to have any control over the R version that is used to build and check the package. In particular I would like to check packages with both the current release and devel versions of R. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea! Check out [R-builder](https://github.com/metacran/r-builder). Good luck.

Comment: R-builder does the job nicely. Presumably the (more convenient) build-in support for R will catch up eventually.